# Databases in psql Don't Show up in PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm using Ubuntu 18. I have PostgreSQL 11 and PgAdmin4 and I connect to PgAdmin4 from my browser by typing localhost/pgadmin4/. Recently, I found that the url doesn't work and internal server error appears. I suppose it was because of some update. Then I connected to psql from my terminal by psql -d analysis -U  command. When I connected to psql by terminal I could see my tables I created before. When I ran pgadmin4 by terminal, a page was opened in my browser and I logged into it by typing my password, but there were no servers and tables I created before. Because working with psql on large tables are problematic, I want to use PgAdmin4 as before and see my tables, how can I make PgAdmin4 to show my servers and tables again? Thanks.

Comment: If they see different things, then they are probably connecting to different hosts, different ports, or different databases.

Comment: pgAdmin is much more problematic than `psql` for large tables. Go for `psql` and never turn back.

Comment: Maybe, I should get used to it. By the way how can I change the host, port or database settings of pgAdmin?